# What are the design guidelines for appindicator icons?

Tags: application-development, icons, indicator, design, pygi

I am creating a Unity AppIndicator using Python + PyGObject, but I wish for it's icon to be in standard Ubuntu style. Where can I find appropriate guidelines for using colours (or is it just white/transparent?), or at least icons of standard AppIndicators? That is about 13.04, as I suppose, the icon style won't change much after this version (though we'll see).

Also, I have a question about setting my icon to my indicator. If I put it in the same folder, as the .py file, how should I refer to it in the code?

Comment: The Ubuntu Humanity icons follow the Tango and Gnome guidelines. Indicators in Ubuntu come in 2 color variants dark and light, you can find the colors by opening one of the SVG files in `/usr/share/icons/ubuntu-mono-X` also you'll find the sizes there.

Comment: Thank you, Uri! I helped.

So, no one can say anything about the second part of my question?

Comment: I'm no expert, but afaik icons should be placed in `usr/share/icons/hicolor/[size]/[category]`.

Comment: OK, where should I state that? In some installation scripts?

Comment: Agreed, few infomration out there on this subject. At least, I was able to find out about "recommended" icons size: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-application/+bug/533439. However, I noticed that many applicaitons distribute 22x22 icons, and also same icons in 24x24 size - not sure why though. Maybe for Gnome?

Answer (score 0):

To use custom icon located in python script folder, use this way (PyGI code snippet)

```
appindicator.Indicator.new_with_path (
   "indicator-name",
   "icon-name",
   appindicator.IndicatorCategory.APPLICATION_STATUS,
   os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
```